Update Last Modified Date One day before in Test Class
How to update last modifed Date  five minutes before in Test Apex class?
Datetime yesterday = Datetime.now().addDays(-1);

Test.setCreatedDate(testLeadTwo.Id, yesterday);
Test.setCreatedDate(testLeadOne.Id, yesterday);
Test.startTest();

Database.executeBatch(new SfToPcRetryUpdateRecords_BatchProcess());

DateTime x5Min = System.now().addMinutes(-5);

List<Lead> ldCreated = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate, lastmodifieddate FROM Lead WHERE 
    lastmodifieddate >= LAST_N_DAYS:1 AND lastmodifieddate < :x5Min];

System.debug('last modified date '+ldCreated);


This might answer your question partially.

If the code you're testing doesn't need to query these records, this can be done via JSON deserialization.
If the code you're testing does need to query these records, it can be done with a CSV file as a static resource + Test.loadData(), but you wouldn't be able to update the datetime for each test.
Probably the best approach would be to consciously design your code in a way that makes it easy to test. For the most part, that means giving yourself a way to inject data in tests instead of creating dependencies directly in the class or hard-coding values.
As an example, this class would be hard to test because the datetime is declared/initialized inside of the method.
public class QueryAccounts {
    // no instance variable we can set + no arguments for the method
    //   = hard to test
    public List<Account> findModifiedInLast5Minutes() {
        // Data declared/initialized inside of a method can't be changed in a test
        Datetime targetTime = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5);

        // Yes, flipping the comparison to what is in the question is on purpose
        // No, it doesn't really make a difference for purposes of this discussion
        return [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= :targetTime];
    }
}

In this trivial example, it's not too hard to make this class easier to test
public class QueryAccounts {
    // We can facilitate testing by making key variables be scoped to the class instead
    //   of to a particular method.

    // One approach is to use @TestVisible (making it public instead is another possibility)
    @TestVisible
    private Datetime targetTime;

    public QueryAccounts() {
        targetTime = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5);
    }

    // You could also provide a constructor (or a setter method) to inject the data
    // This could be public instead (which would mean you wouldn't need the 
    //   TestVisible annotation)
    @TestVisible
    private QueryAccounts(Datetime givenTime) {
        // '??' is the null-coalescing operator, introduced in API v60.0/Spring '24
        // Just a more compact way to deal with potential nulls
        targetTime = givenTime ?? Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5);
    }

    //@TestVisible
    //private setTargetTime(Datetime givenTime) {
    //    targetTime = givenTime ?? Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5);
    //}

    public List<Account> findModifiedInLast5Minutes() {
        // We're not doing anything to declare or set targetTime in the method itself
        //   so we've avoided a situation where we are unable to control this in a test
        return [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= :targetTime];
    }
}

In a test, you then wouldn't need to worry about trying to set the LastModifiedDate.
@isTest
private class QueryAccounts_Test {
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData() {
        // startTest/stopTest in a TestSetup method makes it so that the limits consumed
        //   by the test setup aren't counted against the "normal" limits of each
        //   individual test method
        Test.startTest();

        // Ensuring identifiers like record names are unique helps make it possible
        //   to run tests in parallel
        insert new Account(Name = 'QueryAccounts_Test Account 1');

        Test.stopTest();
    }

    // Since the target time can be set, and we can access it in test contexts
    //   we can (and should) test that it's being set appropriately
    @isTest
    static void defaultConstructor_setsTargetTimeTo5MinutesAgo() {
        Datetime fiveMinutesAgo = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-5);

        QueryAccounts sut = new QueryAccounts();

        // Slightly paranoid assertions so that we don't get screwed over by crossing
        //   a seconds boundary (which is unlikely, but possible)
        Assert.isTrue(sut.targetTime >= fiveMinutesAgo.addSeconds(-1), 'target time was more than one second later than 5 minutes');
        Assert.isTrue(sut.targetTime <= fiveMinutesAgo.addSeconds(1), 'target time was more than one second earlier than 5 minutes');
    }

    @isTest
    static void findModifiedInLast5Minutes_setToAPastTime_returnsAccount() {
        QueryAccounts sut = new QueryAccounts(Datetime.now().addMinutes(-1));

        Test.startTest();
        List<Account> results = sut.findModifiedInLast5Minutes();
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual([SELECT Id FROM Account].size(), results.size(), 'Did not return all expected Accounts');
    }

    @isTest
    static void findModifiedInLast5Minutes_setToAFutureTime_returnsEmpty() {
        QueryAccounts sut = new QueryAccounts(Datetime.now().addMinutes(1));

        Test.startTest();
        List<Account> results = sut.findModifiedInLast5Minutes();
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual(0, results.size(), 'Returned more Accounts than expected');
    }
}

We (mostly) can't directly set LastModifiedDate on the test records, so we can't directly test the logic, but the combination of making the class to be testable and having this particular set of tests makes it as close to direct testing (as least indirect) as can be reasonably expected.

The first test shows that we are setting the target time appropriately
The second test shows that we return records modified after the target time
The third test shows we ignore records modified before the target time
Therefore we would return records modified within the past 5 minutes

